# Better approach for creating multiple records using data mapper?

Tags: php, datamapper

I was wondering which of the following two approaches are better for creating multiple records using the data mapper pattern.

Firstly, a little background: 
I have a web application. The interface is done in Flex/Actionscript and the business logic is done in php. HTTP requests are used to send requests and receive responses from the business logic. The business logic is implemented MVC style. A front controller loads the appropriate controller and executes the appropriate action when a valid request is received.

As far as I understand the data mapper pattern, a model represents a single record/row of the database. The application works great for creating, updating and retrieving single objects.

I am at the point where I would like to create several objects simultaneously. The two approaches I have in mind are as follows:

1. Have the interface perform a create request for each record that needs to be saved.
2. Send an array of all the objects that need to be saved and have the controller call the mapper's save action for each of the items in the array.

Or is there a better way available for creating multiple records?